# Wordpress post loop with incremental value

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a loop that displays a list item (for a slider) for each post looped like so:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"<?php if( $wp_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() ) { ?> class="active"<?php } else { ?><?php } ?>></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

However I need to increase the value of data-slide-to by 1 for each list item it produces. If for instance the loop had 3 posts the end result looking like this:

```
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
```

How can I incrementally increase the data-slide-to value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a counter to while loop:

```
<?php 
  //We want to start with 0 so $counter will be -1
  $counter = -1;
  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $counter++ 
?>

<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $counter; ?>"<?php if( $wp_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() ) { ?> class="active"<?php } else { ?><?php } ?>></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Worked but had to change $counter = 0 to $counter = -1 since I needed it to start with 0 and not 1. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, @jessback, i'm going to update the answer for reference.

Comment: what will be the solution if I have 100 posts and 10 posts per page?